# Passport control: Should we approach one-by-one or as a group?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, borders

My friend and I are currently waiting for our visa applications to be processed. If we end up obtaining a visa, once we travel to the Schengen zone, should we approach the immigration officer together? We are not related in any way other than being friends, so we are not sure if we'd approach it separately or as a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a very narrow grey area but I think it's best to consider it the difference between travelling *together* and traveling merely *with* someone.  Meaning...

- You are traveling **together** with your spouse, boyfriend, parents/kids, some kind of family unit.  Approach **together**.
- You are traveling **with** your friend or business colleague.  Approach **separately**.

Of course, if the officer asks if your travelling with someone, don't be pedantic, just answer yes.  They might ask about the relationship and again, answer truthfully.  These aren't trick questions and lying is far, far worse then your friend being in a different line.

Siblings can go a couple of ways.  If it's just the siblings, approach together.  If any of them have other family, like kids, split up.

Please read all comments.  OP update and additional information there.

Comment: So, the type of relationship determines whether we are traveling "together" or "with someone"? We've known each other for almost 20 years. We are literally traveling together. We even staying at the same places, etc. I think it's safer just to go ahead on separate booths, etc...? We just wanna make sure in case they for some reason ask if we are traveling solo or with someone, etc..

Comment: You are travelling with someone, but since you're not a family unit in the governments eyes, you should approach separately.  If asked, yes, you are traveling with a friend.  If you are in a same-sex relationship, it's ok to approach together in countries where this is *widely accepted*.

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I can only speculate, but I suspect one might take issue with the artificial distinction between "together" and "with."  By their plain meaning, these words are synonyms in this context, and I am unaware of any immigration service that defines them formally.

Comment: **Downvote without explanation is wrong and misleading.  Should be ignored.**

Answer (score 4):

Wait together but walk up to the desk or booth one-by-one, you can always point at each other. Also, don't worry too much, interviews when entering the Schengen area are relatively short and none of this will have serious consequences.

In general, some countries are more specific about this than others but the procedure I outlined is typically the way it's supposed to work. In other places, I have witnessed border guards inviting people to step back and show up one-by-one, even relatives travelling together but, as I said, I think Schengen countries are more relaxed than most about this.

Comment: Since the border guards might ask for personal data, it is only polite to keep some distance, even if the facilities don't allow you to stay completely out of earshot. And they can't know that you two belong together, since you have separate visa.

Comment: @o.m. Well, that part is up to you. And the border guards would know you belong together if you show up together…

Answer (score 0):

If you have a room booked for several persons so these several persons can come together to the border control officer to show the accommodation confirmation. It is a typical situation for the group of people travelling together. Just don't make a big crowd.